# Regular Expression with wildcards to match any character

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I am trying to come up with something that will match a text like below:

ABC: (z) jan 02 1999 \n

Notes:

- text will always begin with "ABC:"
- there may be zero, one or more spaces between ':' and (z).
- Variations of (z) also possible - (zz), (zzzzzz).. etc but always a
  non-digit character enclosed in "()"
- there may be zero,one or more
  spaces between (z) and jan
- jan could be jan, january, etc
- date couldbe in any format and may/may not contain other text as part of it so
  I would really like to know if there is a regex I can use to capture
  anything and everything that is found between '(z)' and '\n'

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is it doing that's different from what you want?

Comment: Please note: I am using regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test my regular expressions.. sorry I should have mentioned this earlier. So using the sample string "ABC: (z) Feb 2 1988\n" .. My result for Group 2 should be "(z) Feb 2 1988"

Answer (score 56):

The following should work:

```
ABC: *\([a-zA-Z]+\) *(.+)
```

Explanation:

```
ABC:            # match literal characters 'ABC:'
 *              # zero or more spaces
\([a-zA-Z]+\)   # one or more letters inside of parentheses
 *              # zero or more spaces
(.+)            # capture one or more of any character (except newlines)
```

To get your desired grouping based on the comments below, you can use the following:

```
(ABC:) *(\([a-zA-Z]+\).+)
```

Comment: Thank you for the expression please see my comment for deltree below

Comment: @chapstick - Added another version that should have group 2 match from the parentheses to the end of the line.

Comment: How does the grouping work? Is there a good tutorial I can use. For example if in the above example, in the string " ABC: (z) Feb 2, 1992\n" if I wanted group 2 to be Feb 2, 1992 instead of (z) Feb 2, 1992... and so on how would I accomplish that? Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Parentheses in regular expressions define groups, which is why you need to escape the parentheses to match the literal characters.  So to modify the groups just remove all of the unescaped parentheses from the regex, then isolate the part of the regex that you want to put in a group and wrap it in parentheses.  Groups are evaluated from left to right so if you want something to be in the second group, make sure there is one set of parentheses before it.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the exact regex implementation you're making use of, I can only give general advice. (The syntax I will be perl as that's what I know, some languages will require tweaking)

Looking at `ABC: (z) jan 02 1999 \n`

- The first thing to match is ABC: So using our regex is `/ABC:/`
- You say ABC is always at the start of the string so `/^ABC/` will ensure that ABC is at the start of the string.
- You can match spaces with the `\s` (note the case) directive. With all directives you can match one or more with `+` (or 0 or more with `*`)
- You need to escape the usage of `(` and `)` as it's a reserved character. so `\(\)`
- You can match any non space or newline character with `.`
- You can match anything at all with `.*` but you need to be careful you're not too greedy and capture everything.

So in order to capture what you've asked. I would use `/^ABC:\s*\(.+?\)\s*(.+)$/`

Which I read as:

> Begins with ABC:
>
> May have some spaces
>
> has (
>
> has some characters
>
> has )
>
> may have some spaces
>
> then capture everything until the end of the line (which is `$`).

I highly recommend keeping a copy of the following laying about
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

This should fulfill your requirements.

`ABC:\s*(\(\D+\)\s*.*?)\\n`

Here it is with some tests http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDgsSBlJlY2lwZRiEjiUM/index.html

Futher reading on regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I am using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test my regular expressions.. sorry I should have mentioned this earlier. So using the sample string "ABC: (z) Feb 2 1988\n" .. My result for Group 2 should be "(z) Feb 2 1988" ... I am not able to get that using either of the expressions above :(

Comment: @chapstick `capture anything and everything that is found between '(z)' and '\n'` so you want (z) and \n in the group?  And why group 2?

Comment: I want (z) but only things upto and not including '\n'. I purposely avoided detailing why Group 2 .. something else will be using the values in Group 2 to do further processing :)